# BluemixのNode-REDでメール送信に失敗します

Tags: bluemix, gmail

Node-REDのe-mailノードを使ったメール送信に失敗します
右端のdebugのところにError: Invalid loginと表示されます
またe-mailノードの下にsend failedと表示されます

e-mailノードは次のように設定しています

To : Gmailのアドレス
Server :    smtp.gmail.com
Port :      465
Userid :        Gmailのアドレス
Password :  Gmailのパスワード

普段からスマホでGmailの送受信をしているのでパスワードは正しくアカウントも有効なはずです
送信先をe-mailノードで設定するのがいけないのかと考えてmsg.toプロパティで渡しても変わりません
またPort番号を587(TLS)に変えるとSSLのエラーで失敗します
どうすればいいでしょうか

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gmail側のセキュリティ設定によるものと考えられます。

現在のGmailの仕様では、OAuth 2.0に対応していないメーラーを安全性の低いアプリとみなします。そのため、そういったメーラーからのアクセスを許可するよう、アカウント側で設定されている必要があります。
なお、2014年7月より前に作成したGoogleアカウントの場合は、自動的にその設定が有効になっているとのことです。LockTimeOutさんのアカウントはそれ以降に取得されたものでしょうか。

[こちら](http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1409/03/news109.html)に詳細な説明がありますので「原因その１」の対処方法を試してみてください。

Comment: セキュリティ設定によるものでした
Node-REDからメールを送ったタイミングでGmailからそれをブロックしたことを知らせるメールも届いていたのですがドメイン指定受信にしていたので気付きませんでした